# Errors displayed even when the project runs in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

I work with Unity and Visual Studio.

Almost every single keyword is underlined with the red curvy lines (representing error) in all scripts but the game works fine when I play it.

I tried unloading and reloading the solution and rebuilding and building the solution. But that solves my problem only to some extent. I tried restarting Visual Studio and my computer but that doesn't help.

The problem stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703004/visual-studio-displaying-errors-even-if-projects-build) is kind of similar to mine, but the answers do not seem to work with the `UnityEngine` namespace.

Earlier, while working on the same project I didn't get those errors for any reason. I am now getting these errors. I already have checked and installed everything needed.

Comment: If you open your Unity preferences and go to the External Tools section, what do you see selected as your code editor?

Comment: [This related Q&A may also be useful to you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/191628/39518)

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't install the additional Unity tools for Visual Studio. Here's what you need to do to setup Visual Studio to work with Unity: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows

Answer (score 0):

I solved the errors later by mistake, by doing this:

This is what I did -

1. Made new scripts
2. Copied the code of old scripts to the new ones
3. Deleted the old scripts